# SQL Server Datetime issues. American vs. British?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, date-formatting

On my test DB, the dates are displayed in a DD/MM/YYYY format. By displayed I mean when you right click, open table in Management Studio, the returned data are displayed in a DD/MM/YYYY format.

Funny thing is, when I write T-SQL to retrieve records, I have to input a MM/DD/YYYY format to get back the right data. Is there anyway I can align this to a DD/MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) to choose the date format that SQL Server ***expects*** in queries (I think management studio uses client computer's regional settings for display purposes,  not sure though). However, I suggest passing values using parameters instead of embedding them in query statement. You won't encounter any issues if you use parameters. Everything is taken care of.

```
set language us_english
declare @d datetime = '1929/12/18'

set language british
declare @d datetime = '1929/12/18' -- fails
```

To change the server default language:

```
declare @langid int = (select langid from syslanguages where name = 'british')
exec sp_configure 'default language', @langid
reconfigure with override
```

Comment: This is a great but I am looking for a permanent solution rather than a session solution.

Comment: Sweet. FYI the correct table name is sys.syslanguages. Also, I just found out you can changed the default language on a user level as well by going to Security -> User Login -> Properties -> Language. Thanks for that Mehrdad

Comment: Nai: syslanguages alone will work if you are in master database. Adding `sys.` to that line made the scrollbars appear so I shortened it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I *always* use YYYY-MM-DD format (or YYYYMMDD) since it's not culture-specific, and, well, I guess it appeals to me because it's "logical" (especially when followed by a time).

[Edit: I'm just talking about what I put in my SQL scripts to ensure compatibility regardless of the server settings, not what SQL Server "displays"]

Comment: How does one go about changing the T-SQL Datime query defaults to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default language for each indvidual [SQL Server login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191448.aspx). Can't quite remember, but something like this:

```
sp_defaultlanguage @loginame = 'LoginName', @language = 'Language'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass in DATETIME in the format

```
dd MMM yyyy
```

for example

```
"11 JUL 2009"
```

there is never any ambiguity around month and date and therefore you should never have a problem

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, the correct way to solve this is simply to never treat the date as a string. If you pass in a parameter, or use the (typed) column value, then the server's *text* conversion simply isn't a factor. In addition to avoiding the i18n issue, this also reduces your injection attack surface. And it saves a few CPU cycles, too ;-p

If you are using `EXEC` for dynamic SQL, then this should likewise be parameterised via `sp_ExecuteSQL`.

Comment: The dates are acutally stored as DATETIME formats. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I assumed that; my point is that it shouldn't *matter* how the server wants to handle them as text if you simply never (in your system) *treat* them as text.

Comment: Oh right I get what you mean. I normally pass them in as variables but good advice nonetheless. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I try to use the ODBC canonical form of a date wherever possible
{d 'yyyy-mm-dd'} 
This way I know how sql server will interpret it.
It works in TSQL just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Either add this to your web.config file:

```
</system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
</system.web>
```

or you can add this statement on the page:

```
<%@ Page uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" %>
```

Hope this help.