# How to use Convert function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
Sl,No  Name      BirthDay
1      Jojin1    2013-05-12 00:00:00.000
2      jojin2    2012-06-12 00:00:00.000
3      jojin3    2015-04-12 00:00:00.000
```

I have table called Datefunction. In that Birthday in above display format but I need DD/MM/YYYY. I try to convert below Query but Updating successful message, but check with Table not happening changes

```
UPDATE DateFunction
SET BirthDay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),BirthDay,103)
```

Comment: SQL Server stores dates in an internal manner that doesn't *have* a format. And this is a good thing. Do formatting in your presentation layer, not the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I completely agree with **Diamond GreezeR** and **Damein**.

But having said that i know OP can't implement those things right now.

**What you can do?**

```
ALTER Table temp
ALTER column Datecolumn varchar(15)

update temp
set Datecolumn=CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),getdate(),103)
```

Comment: IF have one column called date, in that value are 1999...but I need only 99,(Last two digit) how to convert that /

Comment: **`SELECT RIGHT(convert(varchar(date), 2))`**

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Date'.

Comment: select RIGHT(Convert(varchar(Date),2))

Comment: **`select RIGHT(Convert(varchar,Date),2)`**. Now try. If you want we can have Discussion.

Comment: Date Column 12-12-2013 , I need 12-12-13 how we do that

Comment: **`SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 1), '/', '-') AS [MMDDYY]`**

Comment: **`ALTER TABLE temp
ALTER COLUMN datecolumn varchar(100)
;
update temp
set datecolumn= Convert(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,datecolumn,1),5)
from temp`**. This will work. Please be exact to what you need at the start. **`:(`**

Comment: not getting ? I created Column.. Update that Column with Date values using Replace but same value getting New column also

Comment: @Jojin please repeat this two Query from Start **`ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN datecolumn varchar(100) ; update temp set datecolumn= Convert(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,datecolumn,1),5) from temp`**. They are seperated with **`;`**

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Jojin You need to start freshly. You can do the changes after updating

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store the dates in that format, you can only display them.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10, BirthDay, 103)
FROM [Datefunction]
```

Other options (from my comments below):

1. You could create a text field and store the result of the CONVERT function. See Luv's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16646539/909882
2. Another possibility is to use the [DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) option in SQL Server. However, I think this only sets the format for the session; it does not change it permanently.
3. Also, you could could use SET LANGUAGE to choose the date format that SQL Server expects in queries. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/)… as an example

Comment: Ok This We can view the things. I need to update the table with Convert function, that I am asking ?

Comment: You could create a text field and store the result of the `CONVERT` function.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the `DATEFORMAT` option in SQL Server See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188(v=sql.80).aspx. However, I think this only sets the format for the session; it does not change it permanently.

Comment: And my final suggestion is that you could could use SET LANGUAGE to choose the date format that SQL Server expects in queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/sql-server-datetime-issues-american-vs-british as an example

Comment: First We need to add one Column                                   alter table Datefunction
add NewDate varchar (30) 

After that below Query will update
                                                                     update DateFunction
SET  NewDate =  CONVERT(char(10),BirthDay, 105)

Comment: That's what [Luv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16646539/909882) answered below and I suggested above.