# SQL How to set Constraint date default format MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field date name modified.

My goal to get date update with format `MM-DD-YYYY` when insert or update records.

In the property, I set datatype = date and on the date value and binding option of this field, how to I set to get the date format `MMDDYYYY`

If I use (`getdate`) then I got format `YYYYDDMM`

The reason I asked because I have the query that I want to select the current month

```
SELECT  modified
   from  Contact
   where modified >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -1, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Can you correct this query if the date format YYYYDDMM 
Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: DATE or DATETIME doesn't have a format, unless you're looking to store it as strings instead of binary data which is very bad idea.

Comment: I can  convert  the current date format  to MMDDYYYY but i like to replace the current format .

Comment: Just to add to @Sami's comment, you can impose whatever format you like on the date when you query the data from the table.

Comment: `Date`, `DateTime`, and `DateTime2` types do not have a format and are not stored as a formatted string. You only perceive a format because you are human so the default display shows you the value formatted in ISO8601 notation. The displayed format is not a concern of the persistence layer, it is a concern for the presentation layer where the value is rendered for a human to see it.

Comment: Thank you all for help

Comment: you can change the format look at this question for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645607/how-to-use-convert-function-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks Rishi. I can use that, just some more work.

Comment: So the column `modified` is stored as `varchar` instead of `date`?

Comment: i can use both if if work