# SQL Server : BETWEEN DATES brings records outside the period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am working with an application (EHR system) and needs to bring records with in the specific date range in SSRS record. In the script I format the date variable and applies to the column.

```
Convert(varchar(10), @begdt, 101) + ' 00:00:00' and 
Convert(varchar(10), @enddt, 101) + ' 23:59:59'
```

If I set the begin and end date to 01/01/2017 and 01/31/2017, then it pulls the records that are associated with 02/01/2017. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you converting `datetime` to strings for comparison? [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the dates to strings.   When you do, you allow SQL Server to compare them alphabetically, rather than in actual date order.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a language conflict (US vs UK) and SQL Server is in fact seeing that date as 2nd of January. 
This post offers info on Language and Dates: ([SQL Server Datetime issues. American vs. British?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/sql-server-datetime-issues-american-vs-british))

Answer (score 0):

Don't use between, and set your date formats different:

```
@begdt = '20170101'
@enddt = '20170131'

WHERE column1 >= @begdt AND column2 < @enddt
```

This will take care of your datetime issue