# CAST FUNCTION in SQL SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a login user1 with Default Language as 'British English'. when this is changed to 'English' and run the below query

```
select 
CAST([S1OnsetDATETIME] AS DATETIME)
from
tablename1
```

It doesn't fail, but when the Language is changed to 'British English'it fails with the error message :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

I have to use the 'British English' and how to sort this out?

Comment: Use `convert()` with the appropriate format for your date/time value.

Comment: Better idea - don't store dates as strings.

Comment: What format is your datetime currently as a string and what format are you looking for?  Datetime for British English is dd/mm/yyyy while English is mm/dd/yyyy I believe based on this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/sql-server-datetime-issues-american-vs-british

But you're going to need to convert() like Gordon has suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Datetime issues. American vs. British?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187127/sql-server-datetime-issues-american-vs-british)

Comment: Tried OnsetAwarenessOfSymptomsDate  = CONVERT(DATE,dbo.udfDateOnly(dbo.udfEmptyStringToNull([S1OnsetDATETIME])),120)  still failed